# Switch between search engines on Brave Browser

Tags: search, google-search, brave-browser

I am using the Brave browser on Android and would like to know if there is a way to switch easily between search engines.

This feature exists for Firefox and Opera who provide small icons of different engines when typing in the search bar and you just have to click on the one you want to use. Here is an example with Firefox

[image]

For example, I am mostly using duckduckgo.com but sometimes would like to use Google. I already know I can add "!g" in DuckDuckGo, but I'm looking for something more straightforward.

Given Brave is based on Google Chrome, I guess that it explains why it is not implemented natively, but maybe an alternative exists in Chrome that would do the job on the Brave browser?

Comment: I use Brave too, and you've got that option in Parameters to choose a different search engine. Here, in Europe, it's set to Qwant by default, but you can choose another one in a preset list. Don't know if you can edit the list to add a search engine that's not already there, though.

Comment: @Didier Yes but I already know that. as I said I already switched to duck. what I need is a straightforward and simple way to switch easily like for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using keywords.

Go to Settings -> Search Engines -> Manage Search Engines -> Default Search Engines. There, you will see the keywords for different search engines listed, which you edit to your liking. For example, for Google, the default keyword is :g. So if you prefix your search with :g, it will search on Google, no matter what your default search engine is.

I have modified the keywords as per DDG bangs. For instance, I use !g instead of :g for Google.